# I cant get my java fx project to respond to keyboard event handlers

Tags: javafx

I cant get my javafx project to respond to keyboard events. I want to move the rectangle right and left in response to arrow keys. I registered the controller class in fxml and registered the handling event with the rectangle. Here are my three classes:

here is the main

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application  {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
               String fxmlResource = "/application/SpaceUniverse4.1.fxml";
               Parent panel;
               panel = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlResource));

               //MissionControl controller = new MissionControl();

               Scene scene = new Scene(panel);

               primaryStage.setScene(scene);
               primaryStage.show();

            //panel.requestFocus();
            } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

here is the controller:

```
package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;


public class MissionControl
{

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane universe;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle bullet1;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle bullet2;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle ship;

    @FXML
    private Circle alien00;

    @FXML
    private Circle alien01;

    @FXML
    private Circle alien02;

    @FXML
    private Circle alien03;

    @FXML
    private Circle alien04;

    @FXML
    private Circle alien05;

    @FXML
    private Circle alien10;

    @FXML
    private Circle alien11;


    @FXML
    private Circle alien12;

    @FXML
    private Circle alien13;

    @FXML
    private Circle alien14;

    @FXML
    private Circle alien15;

    @FXML
    private Circle alien20;
    @FXML

    private Circle alien21;

    @FXML
    private Circle alien22;

    @FXML
    private Circle alien23;

    @FXML
    private Circle alien24;//has bullet emanating


    public MissionControl() {}

    @FXML
    void initialize() {}

    @FXML
     void handleKeyboardInput(KeyEvent event) 
    {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT)
            {
               while(ship.getX()>=14) 
               ship.setTranslateX(-5);
            }

            else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT)
            {
                while(ship.getX()<=500) 
               ship.setTranslateX(+5);
            }
    }

    @FXML
    void MouseControl(ActionEvent e)
    {   
    }
}
```

here is the fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>

<VBox prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="500.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MissionControl">
  <children>
    <AnchorPane fx:id="universe" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="500.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">

        <Circle fx:id="alien00" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="22.0" layoutY="22.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien01" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="62.0" layoutY="22.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien02" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="22.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien04" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="182.0" layoutY="22.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien10" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="22.0" layoutY="62.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien11" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="62.0" layoutY="62.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien12" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="62.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien13" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="142.0" layoutY="62.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien03" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="142.0" layoutY="22.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien14" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="182.0" layoutY="62.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien20" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="22.0" layoutY="102.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien21" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="62.0" layoutY="102.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien22" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="102.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien23" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="142.0" layoutY="102.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien05" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="222.0" layoutY="22.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien15" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="222.0" layoutY="62.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="alien24" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="182.0" layoutY="102.0" radius="14.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Box layoutX="230.0" layoutY="299.0" />
        <Rectangle fx:id="ship" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#e10707" height="47.0" layoutX="236.0" layoutY="476.0" onKeyPressed="#handleKeyboardInput" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="28.0" />
        <Rectangle fx:id="bullet2" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#000e1b" height="18.0" layoutX="178.0" layoutY="116.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="9.0" />
        <Rectangle fx:id="bullet1" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#010e1b" height="18.0" layoutX="246.0" layoutY="413.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="9.0" />
  </children>
     <cursor>
        <Cursor fx:constant="S_RESIZE" />
     </cursor>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: `Rectangle` is not an input control, and by default receives no input focus. Key events only work when the node has the input focus.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: You need to either make it focus traversable via `focusTraversable="true"` in FXML (`ship.setFocusTraversable(true)` in controller), or programmatically requests for the focus via `ship.requestFocus()`. The former method may require you to press `Tab` key until the rectangle receives the focus, then it will start receiving key events. Also note that by making a node focus traversable, the focus traversal engine may also consume key events, which may interfere with what you are trying to do.

Comment: where should i put ship.requestFocus()?

Comment: i also made it focus traversable and pressed tab and the arrow keys many times, but nothing happened.

Comment: `while(ship.getX()>=14) ship.setTranslateX(-5);` is potentially an infinite loop.

Comment: i changed it to:  @FXML
  void handleKeyboardInput(KeyEvent event) 
 {
     //ship.requestFocus();
     int currentX=0;
     
     if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT)
      {
         currentX = currentX - 5;
      while(ship.getX()>=14) 
      { ship.setTranslateX(currentX);
      break;
      }
      }
      
      else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT)
      {
       currentX = currentX + 5;
      while(ship.getX()<=500) 
      { ship.setTranslateX(currentX);
      break;
      }
     
      }
 }       and i was able to move it once to the right.

Comment: I can't move it to the left, or more than once. tab or no tab made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you handle method to this the reason you couldn't move it more than once was that you were using .getX() which was returning 0 this worked for me good luck

```
@FXML
void handleKeyboardInput(KeyEvent event) {
    int currentX = (int) ship.getLayoutX();
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT && ship.getLayoutX() >= 14) {
        currentX = currentX - 5;
        ship.setLayoutX(currentX);
    } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT && ship.getLayoutX() <= 500) {
        currentX = currentX + 5;
        ship.setLayoutX(currentX);
    }
}
```

Use this if you want to accept input on the whole screen for key presses

```
universe.getParent().getScene().setOnKeyPressed(this::handleKeyboardInput);
```

Comment: to my understanding this would cjange the fxml file itself, which i dont want. and why would the getX be 0 after one RIGHT press?

Comment: Put this in you event and look for yourself `System.out.println("GetX:"+ship.getX()+" GetLayout:"+ship.getLayoutX());`

Comment: You cannot change a fxml from a running program it just loads the file to a pane the fxml never changes

Comment: Glad it worked can you accept the answer by clicking the check next to the question so that others don't think the topic is still open